# Is it a good idea? A company to "buffer" income to be withdrawn in the future

Tags: taxes, international

Before talking to a tax advisor, I'd like your inputs and your experience.

#### This is very important:

- I'm a **permanent resident in Japan**, French-citizen
- My marginal rate is high, I'd pay 50+% on any extra income.
- My business happens **outside the US**, in Asia.
- 100-200k US$/year of corporate gross income

I'd like to establish a company to "buffer" my extra income I consider as bonus. And retrieve the money in few years once my marginal rate will be lower, or in a more advantageous situation. Possibly, I could move for a year to a different country.

I was thinking about many countries, with trade-offs. (Eg. Hong-Kong, Singapore, Delaware and Wyoming?!)

#### Questions

I'd like to talk about the `Delaware C-corp` since SE seems more knowledgeable about it. A Delaware **LLC** isn't suitable since it's a pass-through (sole-proprietor) system and I'm sure I'll be taxed based on my Japanese marginal rate (cf. USJP treaty). It would completely defeat the purpose of a company.

I shouldn't pay anything other than the `Federal tax` 8.7% on gross income and a `Registered Agent Fee`.

- How easy is it to withdraw my company's money in the future? What else need to be payed at that moment?
- The C-corp withholding dividend tax seems to be 30% if non-resident. What's the point of a Delaware in my situation?

*Edit: Writing the post, I think, Delaware or not doesn't matter, it's a C-corp, no advantage.*

- What would you do in my situation (to buffer income to be withdrawn later)?

Other countries:

- HK's profits tax is also around 8% with no dividends tax. If I move there for long enough to be considered tax-resident, I'll be able to withdraw all the money without being taxed. But the incorporation is costly for non-resident.
- Singapore is a bit better, in my gross income range, it's basically 0% for 3years, ~8% after that. No dividends tax. Costly for non-resident.

Comment: You're not mentioning your citizenship. If you're a US citizen, not only will any of that not work, but you'll have additional tax consequences for having a foreign company ownership.

Comment: I added it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I shouldn't pay anything other than the Federal tax 8.7% on gross income and a Registered Agent Fee.

Corporate tax rate in the US is 21% for 2023. Where does the 8.7% come from?

You would also need to pay yourself a reasonable salary as the corporate employee if you're doing any work for the company, which it sounds like you intend to. For that the corporation needs to be registered in Japan as your employer, pay you a salary, payroll taxes and benefits.

Since you derive corporate income in Japan, the corporation may also be subject to Japanese corporate tax regime, which I'm not familiar with.

Last but not least, C-Corps have to pay an additional tax on earnings they do not distribute to their owners, specifically to prevent the scenario you're describing. That's an additional 20% on earnings retained beyond $250K.

> How easy is it to withdraw my company's money in the future? What else need to be payed at that moment?

Easy, if you have proper accounting and reporting set up. The distributions would be considered dividends and taxed as such.

> The C-corp withholding dividend tax seems to be 30% if non-resident. What's the point of a Delaware in my situation?

None. I don't know why people are so hung up on Delaware for their small business. Delaware's Court of Chancery is why large businesses want to be in that jurisdiction, but for any individual small-business owner it is very unlikely to ever be relevant.

> What would you do in my situation (to buffer income to be withdrawn later)?

Most tax jurisdictions have laws to prevent this, as I've shown in the case of US C-Corps. It is very unlikely that you'd succeed in this without engaging a specialist tax adviser proficient in tax avoidance techniques in your jurisdiction.

Comment: Regarding the 8.7%: https://revenue.delaware.gov/business-tax-forms/filing-corporate-income-tax/  and many other official links.

Comment: Could you source your 2nd statement? I assume it's mandatory for US companies only.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation about Delaware.

Comment: @Alexis re 8.7% - that's the **State** tax (in Delaware). That's not the Federal tax. Re the salary - yes, if you're creating a US C-Corp in DE then that's the rule, I don't know anything about HK or SIN or France.

Comment: I don't want to avoid paying tax at all. I want to lower the immediate corporate tax since I can't deduct anything before 2-3years. I must check if the other countries also have such an additional tax on non-distributed income. I really thought that buffering money was common and didn't know it was such a big deal ($250K's limit is enough for me though).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the confirmation DE C-corp isn't great for me! I've learned a lot!

Comment: Is there a specific English term (law?tax?) for the addition tax on non-distributed earnings?

Comment: In the US this type of companies is called "personal holding company", and there's actually additional tax rules about it on top of what I described. In some places they call it "wallet companies" or "personal companies"

Comment: I'll search and learn more before meeting a professional, thanks again!

Comment: I guess I could invest the undistributed earnings in stocks or other expenses to avoid the additional tax. I'm sure there are ways.

Comment: @Alexis in C-Corp? Why on Earth would you do that? It's not going to help with the retained earnings tax, but the capital gains tax on individuals is much lower than on corporations (whatever your tax rate in JP is, compare to the Federal 21% corp level + 30% dividend tax rate to non-resident + JP dividend tax).

Comment: I guess I have enough information to actually contact an expert now. It almost makes no point for me to work more if I get only half of my income but I'll see with the expert. Thanks!